# Where are the Shell Profile Settings Stored?

Tags: linux, configuration, kde, profile, konsole

I just broke a machine running Linux Mint with KDE 4. Thankfully I managed to back up `/home/`, so I have all my data. Now I've installed Kubuntu with KDE 5, and I'm trying to configure my Shell colorscheme to match my previous setup.

I usually created a variant on "Linux Colors" in "Shell Profiles". Where can I find this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean the KDE Konsole shell profiles and their color schemes.

These are usually saved in `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/`.

Custom shell profiles use the extension `.profile`, custom color schemes use `.colorscheme`.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu 21.04 i found in ~/.local/share/konsole/.profile